# PostgreSQL Replication to a Different Schema

Tags: postgresql, replication

I want to consolidate 3 different production databases into a single reporting database.

Let's say we have 3 production databases:

1. Prod 1
2. Prod 2
3. Prod 3

What I want to do is to replicate data from those 3 databases into a reporting database into 3 different schemas (1 schema for each database - there are tables with the same name across databases, so different schema names are required).

All the databases are Postgres 12 instances.

My question is basically the same as [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57341/postgres-streaming-replication-to-a-different-schema-on-another-server) posted 7 years ago. The answer there suggests to wait for Logical Replication. So it's now released but it doesn't support replication to a different schema.

There is also [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/227740/logical-replication-to-different-schema-name) which is again the same as mine. The answer there suggests to rename the schemas on source databases which is not possible in my case.

Is there a 3-rd party tool which will allow to logically replicate data to a different schema? I'm open to using any third-party tools for this, even paid ones.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with logical replication, because logical replication requires that schema name, table name and column names are identical on the primary and the standby server.

I don't know if Slony-I supports that, you could have a look.

Comment: It seems from [this old thread](https://slony1-general.slony.narkive.com/FGqqk3qP/change-the-slave-s-table-name) that it's not possible in Slony as well